# Get struct from a mod that is result of a function

Tags: rust

How can i share struct from a mod that is result of a function, so that every time i need environment variable i will not rerun env::get() function.

src/main:

```
mod env;

async fn main() {
    println!("{}", env::get().profile);
    println!("{}", env::get().redis);
}
```

src/env:

```
use serde::Deserialize;
extern crate dotenv;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Config {
    pub redis: String,
    pub profile: String,
}

pub fn get() -> Config {
    dotenv::dotenv().expect("Failed to read .env file");

    let env = match envy::from_env::<Config>() {
        Ok(config) => config,
        Err(e) => panic!("{:#?}", e),
    };

    env
}
```

---

If i use `lazy_static` as mcarton suggested, how can i get ENV in main?

src/env:

```
 use serde::Deserialize;
    extern crate dotenv;
    
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Config {
    pub redis: String,
    pub profile: String,
}

pub fn get() -> Config {
    dotenv::dotenv().expect("Failed to read .env file");

    let env = match envy::from_env::<Config>() {
        Ok(config) => config,
        Err(e) => panic!("{:#?}", e),
    };

    env
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref ENV: Config = {
        dotenv::dotenv().expect("Failed to read .env file");

        let env = match envy::from_env::<Config>() {
            Ok(config) => config,
            Err(e) => panic!("{:#?}", e),
        };

        env
    };
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`std::sync::Once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Once.html) or [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.4.0/once_cell/#lazy-initialized-global-data) by any chance?

Comment: @mcarton looks like it, if it easiest solution.

Comment: @mcarton but how can i get ENV in main then?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
use serde::Deserialize;
extern crate dotenv;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct EnvConfig {
    pub redis: String,
    pub profile: String,
}

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref ENV: EnvConfig = {
        dotenv::dotenv().expect("Failed to read .env file");

        let env = match envy::from_env::<EnvConfig>() {
            Ok(config) => config,
            Err(e) => panic!("{:#?}", e),
        };

        env
    };
}

pub fn get() -> &'static ENV {
    &ENV
}
```